# docker does not connect to bridge network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container and I want to connect to DB, the docker host machine has a IP `X.X.2.26` and the database `X.X.2.27`. I tried to connect the network in bridge mode. But I can't connect to te database. The host machine has connection to database.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
​
networks:
  sfp:
    name: sfp
    driver: bridge
​
services:
  sfpapi:
    image: st/sfp-api:${VERSION-latest}
    container_name: "sfp-api"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8082:8081"
    networks:
      - sfp
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Mexico_City
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
​
  app:
    image: st/sfp-app:${VERSION-latest}
    container_name: "app"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - sfp
    environment:
      - API_HOST
```

If I check the networks, it was created successfuly.

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
86a58ac8a053   bridge    bridge    local
1890c6433c09   host      host      local
bab0a88222a3   none      null      local
01a411ad42df   sfp       bridge    local
```

But if I see the inspect to the network, I can't see added containers

```
docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "86a58ac8a05398bb827252b2dbe4c99e52aedf0896be6aa6c4358c41cf0e766e",
        "Created": "2022-04-06T12:50:09.922881204-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "false",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

This is the inspect to container

```
docker inspect --format "{{ json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}" sfp-api
{"sfp":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":["sfpapi","bab30efe892b"],"NetworkID":"2076ee845b06df6ace975e1cf3fd360eb174ee97a9ae608911c243b08e98aa42","EndpointID":"3837a6f55449a59267aea7bbafc754d0fab6fedad282e280cce9d880d0c299a7","Gateway":"172.26.0.1","IPAddress":"172.26.0.3","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:1a:00:03","DriverOpts":null}}
```

Comment: i would expect this to work without any special Docker settings (even deleting all of the `networks:` blocks in the file to use the Compose-provided default bridge network).  How exactly are you trying to connect to the database?  What error do you get?

Comment: I tried to remove all `networks:` but the problem persist. This is the error to try connect to database:
`The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.169.2.27, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out.` If I try telnet from host This is the result: `telnet 192.169.2.27 1433
Trying 192.169.2.27...
Connected to 192.169.2.27.
Escape character is '^]'.
`

Comment: Are you on a linux host or Windows/Mac host? For linux host `localhost` port 1433 from the container should connect, while on windows host have to specify `host.docker.internal` port 1433.